# Using high-level language to verify blocks

Tags: transaction-verification, verification

I would like to know if there exists a low-level library in Python or any other language that automates the process of verifying blocks, i.e. verifying the hash, the merkle root and the transactions. Now, the `bitcoinlib` Python library allows for the first two but I haven't found in it any builtin *transaction* verification method. Can anyone point me to some library that will do this for me? I got stuck in this problem while working on a seemingly unrelated date/time-checking project and to be honest I'm not super confortable yet working with the Blockchain.